# Passing Value from one function to another JS

Tags: javascript, function, sapui5

following problem

I got 2 functions

This is my onInit:

```
onInit: function() {
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).getRoute("CoObject").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    },

    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var sRoute = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Route;
    }
```

and I need to use the Value of `sRoute` in this function:

```
_onWeiterButtonPress: function(oEvent) {
    var oRouter = this._getRouter();
    var AufNr = this.getView().byId("IptAufNr").getValue();
}
```

In need `sRoute` to check which tile the user pressed but I don´t know how to pass the value without setting in global?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: How do you mean this?

Comment: I do not think that you can do that, except if you can pass the value where the _onWeiterButtonPress is called. (Deleted my first comment, because I misunderstood the question)

Comment: declare as this.sRoute, so you can access this throughout the controller.

Comment: @santhosh thx mate this is the solution thx very much

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution can be to set the sRoute value on sessionStorage and use it in _onWeiterButtonPress.
Here is an example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('sRoute', sRoute);//for set the value
sessionStorage.getItem('sRoute';//for get the value
```

Comment: Hi , i should have mentioned that i work with SAP WEB IDE and there i got the Error message: For security reasons its not allowed to work with sessionStorage in an Fiori Application -.-

Comment: Thx dude xD greetz xD

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
        var sRoute = getArgumentsFromRoute(oEvent);
    }

_onWeiterButtonPress: function (oEvent) {

        var oRouter = this._getRouter();
        var AufNr = this.getView().byId("IptAufNr").getValue();
        var sRoute = getArgumentsFromRoute(oEvent);
    }

function getArgumentsFromRoute(oEvent)
    {
        return oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Route;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i get the error Parrsing Error: Unexpected Token getArgumentsFromRoute

Comment: Is the parameter "arguments" available in all oEvent objects?

Comment: Not sure how to check this?

Comment: Console.debug/log the object to the console and have a look in the WebConsole

Comment: And you need to integrate the function in your class or in your code, I just provided PseudoCode

Comment: Solved it with this.getArgumentsFromRoute

Comment: Ok perfect :) please dont forget to upvote and mark my answer as solution :)

Comment: okay maybe you could help with another Problem: Look my _onRouteMatched function is used in my onInit-function so after i get the value for sRoute im loosing the value from sRoute when my onInit function is done -  i hope you know what i mean?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a JS Expert, but then you need to store it as a variable in your object or globally, or as mentioned below in the answers with a sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on objet as second parameter of the navTo methode.

```
    onWeiterPressed: function (oEvent) {

        this.getRouter().navTo("detailView", {
            aufNr: this.getView().byId("IptAufNr").getValue();
        });

    },
```

and then in the view you navigated to:

```
    _onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {

        // Get passed object
        var sObjectId = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").aufNr;

    },
```

All written in the documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it whit help from @santhosh by declaring

```
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.sRoute = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Route;
}
```

now I can navigate from the one View to 3 different views depanding on which Tile the User clicked.

Thx alot